# When to deregister event listeners and scheduled callbacks in Cocos2d-js 3.2

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I'm using Cocos2d-js v3.2 to create custom subclasses of `cc.Sprite` using `extend()`. The instances of that subclass are meant to be clickable (touchable) and require some calculations every frame. For the sake of code readability i would like to register the touch listeners and add scheduler callback inside of the constructor. This way whenever new sprite is created, it'll automatically be ready to use. I have two questions regarding this approach:

1. Is registering listeners in constructor a best place to do such things? Constructor is called before the sprite is added to the node tree, so i'm worried if there might be some side side-effects which i'm not aware right now.
2. When and where should I deregister the touch listeners/scheduler callback? When sprite is removed from the node tree, when it becomes invisible or when the object is destroyed

Code:

```
var MySprite = cc.Sprite.extend({
    ctor: function () {
        this._super();

        this.initUserInput();
        this.initUpdates();
    },
    update: function (dt) {
        // Do some per-frame calculactions
    },
    initUpdates: function(){
        cc.director.getScheduler().scheduleUpdateForTarget(this, 1, !this._isRunning);
    },
    initUserInput: function(){
        var $this = this;
        var listener = cc.EventListener.create({
            event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
            onTouchBegan: function (touch, event) {
                var p = touch.getLocation();
                var rect = $this.getBoundingBox();
                if(!cc.rectContainsPoint(rect, p))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            onTouchEnded: function (touch) {
            },
            onTouchMoved: function (touch) {
            }
        });
        cc.eventManager.addListener(listener, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the constuctor is an ok place to put it (maybe the `init()` method would be a bit better). As for de-scheduling, have you checked if the `cleanup()` method does all you need?

Answer (score 1):

well,when to register and unregister event depends on the situation. the eventManager is independent of the render system, don't worry about side-effects .but you should know the eventListener will effect once you register it, not when you add the node to the node tree, so rigister a listener when you need it.

when you call cc.eventManager.addListener, if the second parameter is a ccnode, then the eventlistener will be automatically unregistered when this node is destroyed. if the second parameter is priority, you should remove the eventlistener manually, when you don't need it.